# How to set chrome extension icon for chrome://extensions/

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I created and published a chrome extension [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/whitebuster/kkgacobcjapebahjhkabbkacbpmddeco?authuser=1).

I provided an icon in chrome web store -> Developer dashboard > WhiteBuster and can see it there.

However, after the extension is installed, if I go to [chrome://extensions](http://chrome://extensions) the icon next to the extension is missing (shows empty puzzle).

How can I make my icon show up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding more icons to your manifest.json file. In your case is possible that you're missing one of the icons, specially the big ones.

Include more sizes like this:

```
"icons": { "16": "icon16.png",
       "48": "icon48.png",
      "128": "icon128.png" },
```

Here's some official documentation:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/icons